# What is this jQuery operator: ≢?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I was watching a YT video and the guy used this strange operator in jQuery (ASP.NET Core MVC) can anyone tell me what it is?

Operator:

[image]

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. It doesn't (and can't) define its own operators. This is just a regular (albeit oddly displayed) JavaScript operator.

Answer (score 0):

That's just `!==`(not equal to(strict)). Their IDE or custom settings display it as `≢` (U+2262)